# Javascript/Typescript anagram String search

Tags: javascript, performance, search, typescript

I've created a random word generator which allows me to create random words/anagrams.

Then I've created Anagram search app to find the angarams when user start typing in inbox.

Could you review this with SOLID principles, Performance, Productions level ready scenarios in mind? Please be critical

```
// Generate random words to be used
class RandomWordGenerator {

  private wordList = [];

  constructor() {
    this.generate().createAnagrams();
  }
  generate() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      this.wordList.push(Math.random().toString(32).substr(2, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)));
    }

    return this;

  }

  createAnagrams() {
    let anagrams = this.wordList.slice(0, this.wordList.length/2).map((str) => {
      return str.substr(2, str.length / 2).split('').reverse().join('')
    })
    this.wordList = [...this.wordList, ...anagrams];

    return this;
  }

  getWordList() {
    return this.wordList;
  }

}


// Create Search index
class SearchIndex {

  private searchResults: Array<String>;
  private indexMap = {};
  private indexMapCharArray = [];

  constructor(private wordService: RandomWordGenerator) {
    this.searchResults = this.wordService.getWordList();
    this.sanitizeList().createIndex();
    console.log(this.searchResults);
  }

  sanitizeList() {
    this.searchResults = this.searchResults.filter((str) => !!str).sort();
    this.searchResults = Array.from(new Set(this.searchResults));

    return this;
  }

  createIndex() {
    this.indexMap = {};
    this.indexMapCharArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.searchResults.length; i++) {
      let sortedStrArr = this.searchResults[i].split('').sort();
      let sortedStr = sortedStrArr.join('')

      if (!!this.indexMap[sortedStr]) {
        this.indexMap[sortedStr].push(this.searchResults[i]);
      } else {
        this.indexMap[sortedStr] = [this.searchResults[i]];

      }
    }

    console.log(this.indexMap);
  }


  getSearchResults(str) {
    let result = this.indexMap[str];
    console.log('SEARCHING');
    return result;;
  }


}

// App
class App {

  constructor(private resultIndex: SearchIndex) {
  }

  start() {
    this.bindEvents();
  }

  bindEvents() {
    let element = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('.search-field');

    element.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      let target = <HTMLInputElement>e.target;
      console.log(target.value, e);
      console.log(this.resultIndex.getSearchResults(target.value))
    })
  }
}


window.onload = () => {
  var el = document.getElementById('content');
  var generator = new RandomWordGenerator();

  let searchIndex = new SearchIndex(generator);
  let app = new App(searchIndex);

  app.start();

};
```

Comment: very good, but you should change the accepted answer on your chrome remote desktop question, to Gabriel's answer as that is the correct one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite a nice idea for a learning project.

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7qmkLpmn/) to test your code. Initially I was not able to run your program, as there were a few minor bugs, most relevant:

When you use `element.addEventListener`, the `this` context of your `App` instance is not captured, even though you are using an arrow function. This leads to `this.searchIndex` being `undefined` when the `keyup` event handler is executed. I fixed this, by introducing a local variable before the handler:

```
const index = this.resultIndex;
element.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  let target = <HTMLInputElement>e.target;
  console.log(target.value, e);
  console.log(index.getSearchResults(target.value))
})
```

You can also bind the `this` context to your handler explicitly, if you prefer.

```
element.addEventListener('keyup', ((e) => {
  let target = <HTMLInputElement>e.target;
  console.log(target.value, e);
  console.log(this.resultIndex.getSearchResults(target.value))
}).bind(this))
```

I wasn't able to transpile the arrow function with direct return of the double-negated `str` and changed it to

```
(str) => { return !!str; }
```

even though

```
str => str
```

does the same (with respect to the `filter` function.)

### Coding Style

I have some remarks regarding your coding style.

1. You use semicolons inconsistently. I would prefer to always use semicolons at the end of a statement.
2. `const` vs. `let`: You should use `const`, whenever you don't intend to reassign the given variable, which is almost always the case - except `string` concatenations and declaration before assignment.
3. implicit return types (e.g. in `RandomWordGenerator::getWordList()`) are not very helpful. If you make the return type explicit, i.e. `getWordList() : string[]`, the compiler will enforce all code paths to return a value, which helps to reduce programming errors.
4. implicit parameter types: the `SearchIndex::getSearchResults(str)` method does not specify the parameter type explicitly, but rather implicitly by naming the parameter `str`. Use `getSearchResults(searchTerm : string)` instead and two things are resolved at the same time: First your parameter type is specified, and second, your parameter name is way more relevant in the context of the usage of this method. This is a problem that occurs more often in your code, also with variables. `sortedStrArr` could be defined as `sortedCharacters : string[]` and `sortedStr` could be `sorted : string`. You could also make the member variable types explicit. `indexMap` should be `index : {[key : string] : string[]}`
5. using `private` methods for methods that don't need to be accessible from the outside. In your code all of `SearchIndex`'s methods, except `getSearchResults` could be private.
6. unused code: You call `document.getElementById('content');` without ever using the returned element. The member variable `indexMapCharArray` is reset to an empty array, but never used.

I am not a big fan of the method chaining in `RandomWordGenerator` either. The chaining as you implement it does not prevent the user of your code to call `createAnagrams` before calling `createWords`.

### SOLID Principles

A scenario for extending your application could be to replace the random word generation with e.g. an English dictionary. I assume that in the real world use case one would also only want to find the anagrams already present in the dictionary.

Currently this is not possible without touching the `SearchIndex` class, which is unfavorable coupling. Also I'm not very satisfied with the fact, that `SearchIndex` does need to call the `getWordList()` method of `RandomWordGenerator`.

I would recommend the following signature of `SearchIndex`'s constructor:

```
constructor(private wordList : string[])
```

This way you don't depend on the way the word list is generated to provide it to the `SearchIndex` anymore.

If you want to allow the user to provide multiple sources of word lists, you could have an `interface` for this:

```
interface IWordListSource {
    getWordList() : string[];
}
```

and make `RandomWordGenerator`, `DictionaryWordSource` or other implementations `implement` that interface. It would be okay to inject that interface into the `SearchIndex`, like `constructor(private wordListSource : IWordListSource)` instead of directly providing the word list, if you prefer.

Your `App` class is coupled to a specific document structure, i.e. the existence of an input element with the class `search-field` is required. I would recommend to inject this element into the `App` instance either when calling `start()` or when constructing the instance.

One should also think about, whether logging to the browser's console is the best way of outputting information to the user of your program.

Comment: Wow, excellent first answer. Welcome to CodeReview.